# how to run sequence functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to run sequence functions in JavaScript:
I've 4 functions like this:

```
function myfunction()
{
   callfunction1();
   callfunction2();
}
```

In callfunction1:

```
function callfunction1()
{
    callfunction3();
}
```

My problem is in "myfunction" when I call "callfunction1",callfunction1 is run and it call "callfunction3" but when "callfunction3" haven't finish,"callfunction2" is running.Have anyway to wait "callfunction3" finish then "callfunction2" is run ?

Comment: It's called JavaScript Callback Functions. Read: http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single-threaded, `callfunction2` will only run after `callfunction3` has compeletely finished.

However, if `callfunction3` contains some AJAX or other asynchronous operation, then that will always happen after `callfunction2` (because of the single-threaded thing, it can't start the asynchronous callback until after the synchronous stuff is done). Anything that relies on the result of an asynchronous function MUST either be in the function itself, or called by said function.

Comment: "called by said function",can you explain it to me ?

Comment: The call to `callfunction2` must be inside the asynchronous callback.