# async function returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: facebook, asynchronous, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write a function that takes a URL and returns the engagement stats from Facebook Graph API against that URL. But I am facing trouble as my function is just giving me `Promise { <pending> }` as output.

Here is my code:

```
const getFacebookStats = async (link, ACCESS_TOKEN) => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/?id=${link}&fields=engagement&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
    );
    return resp;
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle Error Here
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling this function ? `getFacebookStats` is an asyncronous function, ans so it will return a promise. Are you awaiting it ?

Comment: I try something like `const response = await getFacebookStats(link, ACCESS_TOKEN)` then  `console.log(response)`, this produces an error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function like this:

```js
getFacebookStats(link, ACCESS_TOKEN).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Or you could call it using await inside an async function.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549569/12036506) answer for a more detailed explaination of Promises in javascript.

Comment: Thanks the link to the detailed answer really helped a lot.